# Yoast - Custom Taxonomy - primary category

Tags: custom-taxonomy, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I have a Custom Taxonomy with the name country. I would like to display the primary category only. I have the yoast plugin installed and that is how I'm setting the primary category.

I'm using this code I found to do the same thing but with post categories and it works well.

```
<?php
$primaryCat = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_ID());
$primaryCat = $primaryCat->get_primary_term();
$primaryCat = get_cat_name($primaryCat);

$categories = get_the_category();
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
   $defaultCat = $category->name;
   $defaultCatLink = get_category_link( $category->term_id );
}

if ( $primaryCat !== "" ) {
   $cat = new WPSEO_Primary_Term('category', get_the_ID());
   $cat = $cat->get_primary_term();

   $catName = get_cat_name($cat);
   $catLink = get_category_link($cat);

} else {
   $catName = $defaultCat;
   $catLink = $defaultCatLink;
}
?>

<h3><a href="<?php echo $catLink; ?>"><?php echo $catName; ?></a></h3>
```

I would be very grateful if someone could help me figure out how to get the primary category and display it for a custom taxonomy?

Thank you for taking the time to look at my problem!!

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it works. Shout out to WP Munchies! https://wpmunchies.com/display-primary-category-using-yoasts-make-primary-feature/

```
<?php
// Fill in your custom taxonomy here
$yourTaxonomy = 'CUSTOM_TAXONOMY';
// SHOW YOAST PRIMARY CATEGORY, OR FIRST CATEGORY
$category = get_the_terms( $postId, $yourTaxonomy );
$useCatLink = true;
// If post has a category assigned.
if ($category){
    $category_display = '';
    $category_link = '';
    if ( class_exists('WPSEO_Primary_Term') )
    {
        // Show the post's 'Primary' category, if this Yoast feature is available, & one is set
        $wpseo_primary_term = new WPSEO_Primary_Term( 'event_cat', get_the_id() );
        $wpseo_primary_term = $wpseo_primary_term->get_primary_term();
        $term = get_term( $wpseo_primary_term );
        if (is_wp_error($term)) { 
            // Default to first category (not Yoast) if an error is returned
            $category_display = $category[0]->name;
            $category_link = get_bloginfo('url') . '/' . 'event-category/' . $term->slug;
        } else { 
            // Yoast Primary category
            $category_display = $term->name;
            $category_link = get_term_link( $term->term_id );
        }
    } 
    else {
        // Default, display the first category in WP's list of assigned categories
        $category_display = $category[0]->name;
        $category_link = get_term_link( $category[0]->term_id );
    }
    // Display category
    if ( !empty($category_display) ){
        if ( $useCatLink == true && !empty($category_link) ){
        echo '<span class="post-category">';
        echo '<a href="'.$category_link.'">'.$category_display.'</a>';
        echo '</span>';
        } else {
        echo '<span class="post-category">'.$category_display.'</span>';
        }
    }

}
```